# ERROR 1366 (22007): Incorrect string value: '\xAB\xB8\xA3\xCBA/...'

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I am trying to encrypt data in mariadb table but it is giving me error. Please find the details below and help me to get it resolved.

**Table Info:**

```
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
Field   Type    Null    Key Default Extra
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
data    varchar(250)    YES     NULL    
+-------+--------------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

**Error while inserting Data:**

```
MariaDB [mydb]> insert INTO test (data) VALUES (aes_encrypt('mydata','key123456'));
```

> ERROR 1366 (22007): Incorrect string value: '\xAB\xB8\xA3\xCBA/...' for column `mydb`.`test`.`data` at row 1

**MariaDB Version**

mariadb Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.5.15-MariaDB, for debian-linux-gnu (aarch64) using EditLine wrapper

**OS Details**

Linux raspberrypi 5.15.32-v8+ #1538 SMP PREEMPT Thu Mar 31 19:40:39 BST 2022 aarch64 GNU/Linux

Comment: Try storing it as a VARBINARY instead of VARCHAR. or encode it with `TO_BASE64()`.

Comment: Possibly a character set/encoding issue? Results when searching that error point to sets/encodings like `utf-8`, `Latin1`, etc. instead of something like `utf8mb4`, etc. Or, is the string too long? `varchar(250)` doesn't seem like enough length to store encrypted data. Although I'd expect a different error/warning, like "data truncated ...".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result of `aes_encrypt` function is always a binary and must be stored as a binary. That means you have to define your column either as a varbinary() or blob type.

`aes_encrypt` uses ECB encryption with padding, therefore a binary column must always be defined larger than the maximum length of a character string: varbinary size= 16 * ((int)(max_string_size / 16) + 1)

**Hint:** `aes_encrypt()` implementation of MariaDB uses a 128-bit key. Keys with shorter size  will be xored and padded which lowers security.